# Como Dar SaveAs no I.E

Tags: vba

Estou com um problema em realizar download de um arquivo via vba, pois quanto eu consigo abrir o documento (formato pdf) eu consigo salvar ele com nome e o local tranquilamente, porem quanto ele não abre no próprio navegador, ou seja, quando é um arquivo .doc ele abre apenas a aba abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo fazer o download dele, apertando o Salvar com o SendKeys, código abaixo:

```
Application.SendKeys "%(s)"
```

Porem não consigo determinar o caminho e o loca, gostaria de saber se tem como acessar a seta para baixo e escolher o Salvar Como, assim consigo determinar o local de salvamento e nome.

Já tentei salvar o arquivo pelo URL porem não é possível pois o site tem um bloqueio para esse tipo de operação.

Answer (score -1):

Para o IE11 ou mais recente, isso deve funcionar:

- Shortcut key: Alt + S
- VBA: `Application.SendKeys "%{S}"` (perceba o uso das chaves)

Caso ainda não funcione, tente acrescentar essa variável no código:

```
Dim Report As Variant

Report = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Attrition Report.xls", "Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls")
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470630/how-to-save-file-from-webpage-from-excel-vba

Comment: Bom dia Lucas, eu tentei o SendKeys, mas ele só permite realizar o download, não consigo determinar o local e o nome do arquivo.

Comment: Olá! Mesmo com o uso das chaves? E o Application.GetSaveAsFilename associado à uma variável funcionou?

Comment: Sim, mesmo com o usa das chaves, o getSaveAsFilename também não funciona